# Large image on S3 not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't know why but my image on S3 doesn't show on all iPhone devices.

I tried installing permissions, configuring CORS on S3... but it still doesn't work!

- [Small image showing perfectly](https://yayyaytees.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/DuyTest.jpg)
- [But large image not showing](https://yayyaytees.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/hot_trendy_unisex_catchy_quote_funny_0_sleeves_0_fucks_t-shirt_hoodie_tank_top_1590244070220.46_1625.jpg) (I tried both on Chrome and Safari)

Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the 2nd image file.

While, yes, it does appear correctly in my web browser, I downloaded it to my computer. The downloaded file could not be opened by several of my graphics programs.

On my Mac, it worked in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

So, it's not a problem with iOS. It's a problem with the image file.